# how to install sympy in jupyter note book

Tags: sympy

I have installed anaconda and I am using jupyter notebook. I ran a code in jupyter notebook and faced with this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SymPy'
I installed sympy with conda install -c anaconda sympy
but It still gives the above error.
what can I do know?

Comment: does running `from sympy import *` in your notebook work? i suspect it's `sympy` vs `SymPy`

Comment: thank you so much, it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python imports are case sensitive:

```
from sympy import *
```

should work